# Median : need numeric data

Tags: r, subset, median

Why regular subsetting might not work? I wanted to calculate median from a data.table:

```
    > median(DT.UsersA3[,1])
Error in median.default(DT.UsersA3[, 1]) : need numeric data
```

it is numeric though:

```
> class(DT.UsersA3$Timedif)
[1] "numeric"
```

With iris data frame it works:

```
> median(iris[,3])
[1] 4.35
```

And lexical subsetting also works...

```
> median(DT.UsersA3$Timedif)
[1] 422.046
```

Comment: Have a look at `DT.UsersA3[, 1]` - it is a `data.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example with `iris`:

```
library(data.table)
Iris <- data.table(iris)
median(Iris[,1])
# Error in median.default(Iris[, 1]) : need numeric data
Iris[,1] # is a data.table
Iris[,Sepal.Length] # is a vector
```

To use the number of the column you can follow the comment from Dason:

```
Iris[[1]] # would return a vector 
median(Iris[[1]]) # works
```

Comment: This gives the why it isn't working but not the how.

Comment: Iris[[1]] would return a vector for the first column and should provide an answer